# No module named 'Speech_Recognition' I have installed but still showing module not found

Tags: python, speech-recognition, assistant

I have installed Speech_Recognition :

[image]

and tried to import it
[image]

this error shows up
[image]

Comment: sending images like this is bad practise. Try restarting your Editor. If that doesn't help, it has it's own interpreter, and you either have to install the package there, or change the interpreter to your default python

Comment: Check your pip and python versions using `--version` flag. It seems they are not paired. You can use `python -m pip` instead of just `pip` to make sure it's executed by the same python.

Comment: The program looks like it is called `SpeechRecognition` not `Speech_Recognition`. You may just need to remove the underscore.

Answer (score -1):

```
import Speech_Recognition as sr
```

I just written the wrong statement it should be

```
import speech_recognition as sr
```